# Why is the integral of $\int {1 \over {1+ \sqrt{x}}} dx$ not the same as for $\int{1 \over u}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Why isn't the integral of this:

$$ \int{ 1 \over {1 + \sqrt{2x}} } \cdot dx $$

Equal to $\ln|1 + \sqrt{2x}|$ when one lets u = $ 1 + \sqrt{2x}$

Isn't it true that $ \int{ 1 \over u} \cdot du = ln|u|$?

My book says the answer is $ \sqrt{2x} - \ln|1+ \sqrt{2x}| + C $

How did they get this?

Comment: If $u =1+\sqrt{2x}$ what is $du$? $dx$ and $du$ are in general not the same....

Comment: Is $\int\frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$ equal to $\ln(x^2)+C$? You should untrain yourself from seeing a reciprocal function and jumping to $\ln$ for the antiderivative. That's only true for the reciprocal a linear function whose slope is $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you make the substitution, say, $u=1+\sqrt{2x}$ $(x\ge0)$, then what will the integral look like?, it's 
$$\int \frac1u dx$$
and **not**
$$\int \frac1u du$$
you have to express $dx$ in terms of $du$ if you want the substitution to really work.
In order to solve this integral, I suggest you substitute otherwise:
Let $v=\sqrt{2x}$, then $x=\frac12v^2$, and $dx=vdv$ (for this step I hope you can understand why). Then the original integral can be rewritten (equivalently) as
$$\int \frac{v}{1+v}dv\\=\int(1-\frac{1}{1+v})dv=v-\int\frac{1}{1+v}dv=v-\int\frac{1}{1+v}d(1+v)=v-\ln|1+v|+C$$
And don't forget $v=\sqrt{2x}$, putting it back is also very important.

Comment: So how would I proceed to integrate this?

Comment: I'll add it to my answer. wait a minute.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit confused and my book, which is normally excellent is severely lacking explanations in what I find to be the most difficult problems ye.t

Comment: This is a much simpler solution. The only hint the book gave was to let the denominator of the integrand equal u, which is clearly inferior to this method.

Comment: Wait, why is dx = vdv? I though I understood that bit, but I'm just a little confused.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans. For a not very rigorous explanation,  Remember x is a function of v, so dx/dv=x'=(1/2v^2)'=v. ( sorry I'm on my mobile app now so not convenient for me to use jax)

Comment: I get that now.

Comment: Okay, I understand why (1 - (1)/(1+v)) = ((v)/(1+v)), but how did you get there? How did you know to break it apart in such a way?

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans. You can call that a trick if you like. Just practice more, and you will know how to get on the right track when dealing with such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Why? Just differentiate $\log |1+\sqrt{2x}|$ and remark that the result is not $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2x}}$!

The reason is that after a substitution like $x=x(u)$ you must also insert $dx = x'(u)\, du$. And you did not.